# Regex to find last occurrence of pattern in a string

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

My string being of the form:

```
"as.asd.sd fdsfs. dfsd  d.sdfsd. sdfsdf sd   .COM"
```

I only want to match against the last segment of whitespace before the last period(.)

So far I am able to capture whitespace but not the *very* last occurrence using:

```
\s+(?=\.\w)
```

How can I make it less greedy?

Comment: A fancy PCRE regex: [`^(?>\s*\S+)*\K\s+(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/k9VwC6/4)

Comment: It's an old question but worth to mention, you could just use `.*` to consume anything before: [`^(.*\S)?(\s+)(?=\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/bTgXem/3) (of course in PCRE can be [used with `\K`](https://regex101.com/r/bTgXem/4) as well instead of capturing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try like so:

```
(\s+)(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

`(?=\.[^.]+$)` Positive look ahead for a dot and characters except dot at the end of line.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/k9VwC6/3

Answer (score 17):

**In a general case**, you can **match the last occurrence of any pattern** using the following scheme:

```php
pattern(?![\s\S]*pattern)
(?s)pattern(?!.*pattern)
pattern(?!(?s:.*)pattern)
```

where `[\s\S]*` matches any zero or more chars as many as possible. `(?s)` and `(?s:.)` can be used with regex engines that support these constructs so as to use `.` to match any chars.

**In this case,** rather than `\s+(?![\s\S]*\s)`, you may use

```php
\s+(?!\S*\s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SWeNbb/2). Note the `\s` and `\S` are inverse classes, thus, it makes no sense using `[\s\S]*` here, `\S*` is enough.

**Details**:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `(?!\S*\s)` - that are not immediately followed with any 0 or more non-whitespace chars and then a whitespace.

Comment: Why `(?s)` or the confusing `[\s\S]` instead of simple `.`? IMHO they are only needed when you require `.` to match a newline.

Comment: @pabouk Exactly, see the title: *Regex to find last occurrence of pattern in a **string***, and a string can contain line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

```
"as.asd.sd ffindMyLastOccurrencedsfs. dfindMyLastOccurrencefsd  d.sdfsd. sdfsdf sd   ..COM"

.*(?=((?<=\S)\s+)).*

replaced by `>\1<`

>   <
```

#### As a more generalized example

This example defines several needles and finds the last occurrence of either one of them. In this example the needles are:

- defined word `findMyLastOccurrence`
- whitespaces `(?<=\S)\s+`
- dots `(?<=[^\.])\.+`

```
"as.asd.sd ffindMyLastOccurrencedsfs. dfindMyLastOccurrencefsd  d.sdfsd. sdfsdf sd   ..COM"

.*(?=(findMyLastOccurrence|(?<=\S)\s+|(?<=[^\.])\.+)).*

replaced by `>\1<`

>..<
```

#### Explanation:

**Part 1** `.*`

- is greedy and finds everything as long as the needles are found. Thus, it also captures all needle occurrences until the very last needle.

edit to add:

- in case we are interested in the first hit, we can prevent the greediness by writing `.*?`

**Part 2** `(?=(findMyLastOccurrence|(?<=\S)\s+|(?<=[^\.])\.+|(?<=**Not**NeedlePart)NeedlePart+))`

- defines the 'break' condition for the greedy 'find-all'. It consists of several parts:
  `(?=(needles))`

  - positive lookahead: ensure that previously found *everything* is followed by the needles
    `findMyLastOccurrence|(?<=\S)\s+|(?<=[^\.])\.+)|(?<=**Not**NeedlePart)NeedlePart+`
  - several needles for which we are looking. Needles are patterns themselves.
  - In case we look for a collection of whitespaces, dots or other needleparts, the pattern we are looking for is actually: *anything which is* **not** *a needlepart, followed by one or more needleparts (thus needlepart is +)*. See the example for whitespaces \s negated with \S, actual dot . negated with [^.]

**Part 3** `.*`

- as we aren't interested in the remainder, we capture it and dont use it any further. We could capture it with parenthesis and use it as another group, but that's out of scope here

Answer (score 0):

### SIMPLE SOLUTION for a COMMON PROBLEM

All of the answers that I have read through are way off topic, overly complicated, or just simply incorrect. This question is a common problem that regex offers a simple solution for.

#### Breaking Down the General Problem

1. **THE STRING**

   - The generalized problem is such that there is a ***string*** that contains several characters.
2. **THE SUB-STRING**

   - Within the string is a ***sub-string*** made up of a few characters. Often times this is a file extension (*i.e* `.c`, `.ts`, or `.json`), or a top level domain (*i.e.* `.com`, `.org`, or `.io`), but it could be something as arbitrary as `MC Donald's Mulan Szechuan Sauce`. The point it is, it may not always be something simple.
3. **THE BEFORE VARIANCE** (Most important part)

- The **before variance** is an arbitrary character, or characters, that always comes just before the sub-string. In this question, the before variance is an unknown amount of white-space. Its a variance because the amount of white-space that needs to be match against varies (or has a dynamic quantity).

#### Describing the Solution in Reference to the Problem

---

##### (Solution Part 1)

###### *Often times when working with regular expressions its necessary to work in reverse.*

We will start at the end of the problem described above, and work backwards, henceforth; we are going to start at the ***The Before Variance*** (or #3)

So, as mentioned above, **The Before Variance** is an unknown amount of white-space. We know that it includes white-space, but we don't know how much, so we will use the **meta sequence for Any Whitespce** with the **one or more quantifier**.

- ###### The Meta Sequence for "Any Whitespace" is `\s`.
- ###### The **"One or More" quantifier** is `+`

so we will start with...

###### NOTE: *In ECMAS Regex the `/` characters are like quotes around a string.*

```
const regex = /\s+/g
```

I also included the `g` to tell the engine to set the global flag to true. I won't explain flags, for the sake of brevity, but if you don't know what the global flag does, you should DuckDuckGo it.

##### (Solution Part 2)

Remember, we are working in reverse, so the next part to focus on is the Sub-string. In this question it is `.com`, but the author may want it to match against a value with variance, rather than just the static string of characters `.com`, therefore I will talk about that more below, but to stay focused, we will work with `.com` for now.

It's necessary that we use a concept here that's called **ZERO LENGTH ASSERTION**. We need a "zero-length assertion" because we have a sub-string that is significant, but is not what we want to match against. "Zero-length assertions" allow us to move the point in the string where the regular expression engine is looking at, without having to match any characters to get there.

The **Zero-Length Assertion** that we are going to use is called **LOOK AHEAD**, and its syntax is as follows.

**Look-ahead Syntax: `(?=Your-SubStr-Here)`**

We are going to use the look ahead to match against a variance that comes before the pattern assigned to the look-ahead, which will be our sub-string. The result looks like this:

```
const regex = /\s+(?=\.com)/gi
```

I added the insensitive flag to tell the engine to not be concerned with the case of the letter, in other words; the regular expression `/\s+(?=\.cOM)/gi`
is the same as `/\s+(?=\.Com)/gi`, and both are the same as: `/\s+(?=\.com)/gi` &/or /\s+(?=.COM)/gi. Everyone of the "Just Listed" regular expressions are equivalent so long as the `i` flag is set.

###### That's it! [The link HERE (REGEX101)](https://regex101.com/r/Od8Kp8/1) will take you to an example where you can play with the regular expression if you like.

---

I mentioned above working with a sub-string that has more variance than `.com`.

You could use `(\s*)(?=\.\w{3,})` for instance.

The problem with this regex, is even though it matches `.txt`, `.org`, `.json`, and `.unclepetespurplebeet`, the regex isn't safe. When using the question's string of...

```
"as.asd.sd fdsfs. dfsd  d.sdfsd. sdfsdf sd   .COM"
```

as an example, you can see at the [LINK HERE (Regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/R4ou1q/1) there are 3 lines in the string. Those lines represent areas where the sub-string's lookahead's assertion returned true. Each time the assertion was true, a possibility for an incorrect final match was created. Though, only one match was returned in the end, and it was the correct match, when implemented in a program, or website, that's running in production, you can pretty much guarantee that the regex is not only going to fail, but its going to fail horribly and you will come to hate it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. It will capture the last white space segment - in the first capture group.

```
(\s+)\.[^\.]*$
```