# Regex match last occurrence in the text

Tags: regex

I have this regex: [link](https://regexr.com/78b8j)

```
((?<=<li><a href="\/bi-platform.*\/">bi-platform.*<\/a><\/li>).*)
```

That is matching the first occurrence of

```
<li><a href="/bi-platform940/">bi-platform940</a></li>DONTWANTTHIS
<li><a href="/bi-platform887/">bi-platform887</a></li>DONTWANTTHIS
<li><a href="/bi-platform953/">bi-platform953</a></li>WANTTHIS!!
iiiiioioioioi
kllkmkmkm
lçm
```

How can I match the last occurrence? (WANTTHIS!!) (I don't want to match this word it can be something else)

Comment: what language? couldn't get get all occurrences then get the last one from results?

Comment: do you want to treat this string as a whole or as lines? to you only want the word after the last `</li>` tag?

Comment: anyway, in regexr turn on the "global" flag, see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to find last occurrence of pattern in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870124/regex-to-find-last-occurrence-of-pattern-in-a-string)

Comment: do you know what a `capture group` is? depnding on your source data, this regex could be as simple as `.*>(.*)`

Comment: Turning on "global" flag is not what I want. Yes I want the word after the last '</li>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.*bi-platform\d+<\/a><\/li>(.*?)\n
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/itFZGE/1)

---

EDIT: To replace the word: https://regex101.com/r/En0r5T/1

Comment: It's almost that. I want to replace the word "WANTTHIS!!". with your regex everything is replaced :P

Answer (score 0):

Turning on "global" flag is not what I want. Yes I want the word after the last `</li>`

You can follow this link: https://regexr.com/78b8j

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).